# Ошибка установки Lubuntu 21

Tags: linux, install, lubuntu

При попытке установить лубунту на диск рядом с виндой 7 выдает ошибку

Установочный диск создан правильно

При попытке установить с автоматической разметкой выбивало ошибку установки загрузчика поэтому решил разметить вручную

Но теперь получаю другую ошибку

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Разметь `gparted live`, а потом ставь на уже созданные разделы.

Comment: После ручной разметки установка завершилась "удачно" но при попытке запуска Система говорит что не видит дисков с которых можно запуститься

Comment: Думал может флаг "boot" слетел но нет partition manager показывает что флаг на месте

Comment: Похоже что проблема в точке монтирования... Комманда "lsblk" показывает что у этих 3 разделов не точек монтирования которые я задавал.  Решил создать с помощью "sudo mount /dev/sda4  /home" После этого точка монтирования отображается в partition manager  НО при перезапуске все точки слетают

Comment: Ну так для этого есть `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена конвертацией MBR в GPT, Огромное спасибо кто помогал))

Comment: на скока я понял изначальная постановка вопроса уже не соответствует ответу )) из за того что система переустанавливалась несколько раз в процессе чего возникали разные _ошибки._ Судя по скрину, по какой-то причине, были неверно установлены права доступа к папке пользователя, одним из решений которых это восстановить эти права, что можно было сделать командой `chown -R nebula:nebula /home/nebula` запущенной от суперпользователя.